# Kotlin, Mockito and Android Test Instrumentation. Lateinit Property has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to mock an UseCase dependency in a test instrumentation.

I am creating a `@Rule` to work with this:

`LocationsUseCaseRule.kt`

```
class LocationsUseCaseRule : ExternalResource() {

    @Mock
    lateinit var locationsUseCase : LocationsUseCase

    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    override fun before() {
        super.before()
        LocationsUseCase.setInstance(locationsUseCase)
    }
}
```

but when I hit on `before()`, the usecase is not loaded.

I have the same implementation in Unit Tests and it works.

These are my dependencies:

```
// Mockito
def mockitoVersion = "2.6.3"
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:' + mockitoVersion
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:' + mockitoVersion
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:" + mockitoVersion

testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin-kt1.1:1.5.0"
```

This is how I set my instance in `LocationsUseCase`:

```
object Singleton {
    var instance: LocationsUseCase? = null
}

companion object {

    fun setInstance(locationsUseCase: LocationsUseCase?) {
        Singleton.instance = locationsUseCase
    }

    fun getInstance(): LocationsUseCase {
        if (Singleton.instance == null) {
            Singleton.instance = LocationsUseCase(
                    LocationsRepository.instance
            )
        }

        return Singleton.instance!!
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the code of `LocationsUseCase.setInstance`?

Comment: I just modified the question. Thanks

Comment: You're passing a non-initialized `locationsUseCase` to `LocationsUseCase.setInstance`, hence the error. Don't you mean `LocationsUseCase.setInstance(LocationsUseCase.getInstance())`?

Comment: Also why are you doing all that when you can simply do `object Singleton {
    val instance = LocationsUseCase(                LocationsRepository.instance)
}`?

Comment: Mmmmm seems to work like that, but I have the same code  (or basically similar) in a unit test, and it works.

Comment: Probably thinking totally opposite is the way to work. I was just migrating from Java to Kotlin and I haven't touched anything, that would work for Java though. Thank you very much! If you can develop a proper answer, I'll mark it as valid

Comment: You're welcome. The code transform from IntelliJ is nice but sometimes generates bloat code, which is logical since Java is more verbose than Kotlin :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this way is simpler and acheives what you want:

```
object Singleton {
    val instance = LocationsUseCase(LocationsRepository.instance)
}
```